# Analyzing the probability of this event

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions

Consider a set $S$ of $n$ different elements. Sample $f(n)$ different elements from $S$ to get a new set $S'$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n} = 0$. Now pick uniformly at random one element $x$ from $S'$ and suppose it lies in the middle third of $S'$. We want to find the probability that $x$ is also in the middle third of $S$ and show that $x$ is also likely to be in the middle third of $S$.

This is my attempt. First, we find the probability that $x$ is the element of rank $i$ in $S$ given that $x$ is in the middle third of $S'$

$$ P_i = \frac{3}{f(n)}\frac{1}{n \choose f(n)}\sum^{\frac{2f(n)}{3}}_{j=\frac{f(n)}{3}+1} {i-1\choose j-1} {n-i\choose f(n)-j}.$$ So the probability we want to look at is $\sum^{\frac{2n}{3}}_{i=\frac{n}{3}+1}P_i$ but I find this expression hard to work with and find a bound for it, what else can I do?

Comment: How is it possible to sample $f(n)$ from $n$ when $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{f(n)} = 0$?

Comment: @XiangxiangXu: Yeah, it was the other way around

Comment: Can I understand it as showing that the conditional probability P(x in the middle third of S| x in the middle third of S') is close to 1?

Comment: @XiangxiangXu: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for

Comment: "and show that x is also likely to be in the middle third of S"

Counterexample: $f(n)=3$

Answer (score 2):

Sketch

Let $S = \{1,2 \cdots n\}$; also, assume $n$ and $m=f(n)$ are multiple of $3$. Let $A$ be the event that the selected element belongs to the middle third of $S$. Let $B$ be the event that the selected element belongs to the middle third of the (random) subset $S'$, Clearly $P(A)=P(B)=1/3$.

We want $P(A|B) = P(B|A)$. Now $$P(B|A) =\sum p(x|A) P(B|A,x) = \frac{3}{n}\sum_{x=n/3}^{2n/3} P(B|x)= \frac{6}{n} \sum_{x=n/3}^{n/2} P(B|x)$$

where in the last equality we've used symmetry.

For fixed $x$ in $[n/3,n/2]$:  Let $Z$ be the number of elements in $S'$ below $x$. Assumming $1 \ll m \ll n$,  $Z$ will be approximately a Binomial, $B(m-1,\frac{x-1}{n-1}) \approx B(m,\frac{x}{n})$.

Then apply [Selbeg's inequaliyy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Selberg%27s_inequality) and hope for the best.